# Sublime Text: how do I edit the multiple line caret insertion key binding?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I can never remember what Sublime Text calls its caret/cursor/line insertion above/below command in the key bindings.

On some platforms it is Ctrl + Alt + Up (or Down) and a caret (for typing) appears on the line above (with Up) or below (with Down), but sometimes this fails... and I spend way too long searching for what they call their feature's command.

This is what their docs refer to it as:
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

They call it "select_lines", here's a snippet that will enable this feature for `ALT + Shift + Up/Down`

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
    { "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} }
]
```